# Prove that $A+B=-2I_{4}$

Tags: matrices

If $A,B\in M_{4}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) :A\neq B;Tr\left( A\right) \neq 0$ and

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
A^2 - 2B + I_4 = 0_4 \\
B^2 - 2A + I_4 = 0_4
\end{matrix}\right.$$

**prove that:** $$A+B=-2I_{4}$$ and $$\det\left( A-aI_{4}\right) \geq \det\left( A+aI_{4}\right) ,\forall a\in \mathbb{R} $$

---

All my ideas ($A^{2}=2B-I_{4};B^{2}=2A-I_{4}\Rightarrow A^{2}B=2B^{2}-B;B^{2}A=2A^{2}-A$) seem to be wrong as long as I can't rich a prove.

Comment: Suppose we look at $A$ and $B$ as complex matrices.  If $v$ is a complex eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  What do the equations say about $Bv$?  And do we get a relation for $\lambda$ by relating the two equations?

Comment: I can't understand this, Could you give me further Information about this?

Comment: Suppose $Av=\lambda v$. Apply both sides of the first equation to $\lambda$. What does it tell you $Bv$ is?