# Problem with matrices and trace

Tags: matrices

Let $A,B$ be $4 \times 4$ matrices with real elements such that $A \ne B$, $tr(a) \ne 0$, $A^2-2B+I_4=O_4$ and $B^2-2A+I_4=O_4$. Show that $A+B=-2I_4$.

My try: I got an expression of $B$ oin function of $A$, substituded and got $A^4-2A^2-8A+5I_4=O_4$ and I am stuck.

Comment: This question was asked 10 minutes ago or so. Look for it, and close this one.

Comment: @DonAntonio May you give me a link, please?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189799/prove-that-ab-2i-4 ....and more like 1 hour ago. Time flies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute the first equation into the four times the second, you get $(A^2 + I)^2 + 4(-2A + I) = 0$. Simplify to get $(A-I)^2(A^2+2A+5I)=0$. Argue that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is ...

- neither $x-1$ nor $(x-1)^2$, otherwise the condition $A\ne B$ will be violated;
- neither $(x-1)(x^2+2x+5)$ nor $(x-1)^2(x^2+2x+5)$, otherwise the condition $\operatorname{tr}(A)\ne0$ will be violated.

Hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $x^2+2x+5$. Now use the condition $A^2-2B+I=0$ to conclude that $A+B=-2I$.